# facebook sdk 7.2 unity 5.2 profile picture pulls though in the editor but not on the facebook canvus?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-canvas, unity-web-player

I have 2 problems currently

Im using unity 5.2.0 and the Facebook unity sdk 7.2
My unity is set to PC build (I will explain why just now)

I have been following the grey zoned tutorials and adapting them where needed for the new SDK. In my unity editor I currently have a place for my profile pic, the username, share and invite buttons along with the Facebook login button. When I run the project, it runs through everything perfectly. It gets the profile picture and the username and puts them where they need to be, the share and invite buttons post in the log that they are working so that's fine. 
My first problem is:
When I put my editor in web player build, I always get this error when i try to log in. Any advice on fixing this part?

> ArgumentException: Cannot overwrite header: User-Agent
>   UnityEngine.WWW.CheckSecurityOnHeaders (System.String[] headers) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/WWW.cs:71)
>   UnityEngine.WWW..ctor (System.String url, System.Byte[] postData,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 headers) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UtilsBindings.gen.cs:125)
>   Facebook.Unity.AsyncRequestString+c__Iterator1.MoveNext () (at
>   Assets/Facebook/Scripts/Utils/AsyncRequestString.cs:100)

My second problem is:
I build my project (web player build) and upload it to my hosted server, then when I hop on Firefox or Internet Explorer and go to my app on the Facebook canvas it loads up, but the profile pic and username do not appear. The sharing and invites work however. Its only the pic and name that do not pull through.

I'm going to put all my code in so that you can see exactly what I have done.
Sorry I'm very new to coding so it probably looks terrible.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.Unity;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class FBholder : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject UIFBIsLoggedIn;
    public GameObject UIFBIsNotLoggedIn;
    public GameObject UIFBAvatar;
    public GameObject UIFBUserName;
    public GameObject ErrorText;
    public Text errorText;

    private Dictionary<string, string> profile = null;

    void Awake()
    {
        FB.Init (SetInit, OnHideUnity);
    }

    private void SetInit()
    {
        errorText = ErrorText.GetComponent<Text>();
        Debug.Log ("FB Init done.");
        //LOG: Error Text
        errorText.text = "FB Init done.";
        Debug.LogWarning("LOG "+ errorText.text);

        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            DealWithFBMenus(true);
            Debug.Log ("FB Logged In.");
            //LOG: Error Text
            FindTheStupidErrorLog();
            errorText.text = "FB Logged In.";
            Debug.LogWarning("LOG "+ errorText.text);

        }else{
            DealWithFBMenus(false);
            FindTheStupidErrorLog();
            errorText.text = "FB Not Logged In.";
            Debug.LogWarning("LOG "+ errorText.text);
        }

    }

    private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
    {
        if(!isGameShown)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }else{
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }

    public void FBlogin ()
    {
        var perms = new List<string>(){"public_profile", "email",};
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);
        //LOG: Error Text
        FindTheStupidErrorLog();
        errorText.text = "FB Logged In.";
        Debug.LogWarning("LOG "+ errorText.text);
    }

    private void AuthCallback (ILoginResult result) 
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
            DealWithFBMenus(true);
            // AccessToken class will have session details
            var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            // Print current access token's User ID
            Debug.Log(aToken.UserId);
            // Print current access token's granted permissions
            foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions) {
                Debug.Log(perm);
            }
            //LOG: Error Text
            FindTheStupidErrorLog();
            errorText.text = "AuthCallback if";
            Debug.LogWarning("LOG "+ errorText.text);
        } else {
            DealWithFBMenus(false);
            Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
            //LOG: Error Text
            FindTheStupidErrorLog();
            errorText.text = "AuthCallback else";
            Debug.LogWarning("LOG "+ errorText.text);
        }
    }

    void DealWithFBMenus(bool isLoggedIn)
    {
        if(isLoggedIn)
        {
            UIFBIsLoggedIn.SetActive (true);
            UIFBIsNotLoggedIn.SetActive (false);

            FB.API (Util.GetPictureURL("me", 128, 128), HttpMethod.GET, DealWithProfilePicture);
            FB.API ("/me?fields=id,first_name", HttpMethod.GET, DealWithUserName);
            //LOG: Error Text
            FindTheStupidErrorLog();
            errorText.text = "running deal with menu If";
            Debug.LogWarning("LOG "+ errorText.text);

        }else{
            UIFBIsLoggedIn.SetActive (false);
            UIFBIsNotLoggedIn.SetActive (true);
            //LOG: Error Text
            FindTheStupidErrorLog();
            errorText.text = "running deal with menu else";
            Debug.LogWarning("LOG "+ errorText.text);
        }
    }

    void DealWithProfilePicture (IGraphResult result)
    {
        if(result.Error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Problem getting Pic");
            //LOG: Error Text
            FindTheStupidErrorLog();
            errorText.text = "Profile Pic Error";
            Debug.LogWarning("LOG "+ errorText.text);

            FB.API (Util.GetPictureURL("me", 128, 128), HttpMethod.GET, DealWithProfilePicture);
            return;
        }

        Image UserAvatar = UIFBAvatar.GetComponent<Image>();
        UserAvatar.sprite = Sprite.Create (result.Texture, new Rect(0,0,128,128), new Vector2(0,0));
        //LOG: Error Text
        FindTheStupidErrorLog();
        errorText.text = "Profile Pic loaded";
        Debug.LogWarning("LOG "+ errorText.text);
    }

    void DealWithUserName (IGraphResult result)
    {
        if(result.Error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Problem getting Pic");
            //LOG: Error Text
            FindTheStupidErrorLog();
            errorText.text = "UserName didnt loaded";
            Debug.LogWarning("LOG "+ errorText.text);

            FB.API ("/me?fields=id,first_name", HttpMethod.GET, DealWithUserName);
            return;
        }

        profile = Util.DeserializeJSONProfile(result.Text);

        Text UserMsg = UIFBUserName.GetComponent<Text>();

        UserMsg.text = "Hello, " + profile["first_name"];
        //LOG: Error Text
        FindTheStupidErrorLog();
        errorText.text = "UserName loaded";
        Debug.LogWarning("LOG "+ errorText.text);   
    }

    public void ShareWithFriends()
    {
        if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            FBlogin();
            Debug.Log ("not logged in to share");
        }else {
            Uri contentUri = new Uri("http://apps.facebook.com/" +FB.AppId + "/?challenge_brag=" + (FB.IsLoggedIn ? AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserId : "guest"));


            FB.ShareLink(
                contentURL: contentUri,
                contentTitle: "Me Testing the FB SDK",
                contentDescription: "I wonder where this shows?",
                photoURL: new Uri("https://dragondigital.co.za/fb_7.1_test/mascotOne.png"),  
                callback: ShareCallback
                );
        }
    }

    private void ShareCallback (IShareResult result)
    {
        if (result.Cancelled || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error)) {
            Debug.Log("ShareLink Error: "+result.Error);
        } else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.PostId)) {
            // Print post identifier of the shared content
            Debug.Log(result.PostId);
        } else {
            // Share succeeded without postID
            Debug.Log("ShareLink success!");
        }
    }

    public void InviteFriends()
    {
        FB.AppRequest(

        message: "This is the Invite Message",
        title: "This is the Invite Title."
        );

        print ("Invite prob worked");
        //LOG: Error Text
        FindTheStupidErrorLog();
        errorText.text = "Invite prob worked";

    }

    public void FindTheStupidErrorLog()
    {
        if(errorText == null)
        {
            errorText = ErrorText.GetComponent<Text>();
        }
    }


}
```

Yes i know there is ALOT of redundant error logging but that will be taken out later :)

Any help you guys can give will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi Oscar! did u solve this? I´m in the same problem, i dont know if we could run perfectly an app in standalone, do you find a answer?